# How to Save data and append to it every time the code runs

Tags: python

I am trying to create a database to save data generated from the below code.

My issue is that every time I am run the code it is overwriting the existing data with the newly generated data from the function, which makes sense as every time the code is run it reads the data_list as empty.

*My question* is how to save the data generated from the code and add to it every time I run the code with new information.

I am trying to get the First name and Last name as an exercise from the URL and add it to `data = [[first_name, last_name]]` which will be added afterward to `data_list=[]`

My required outcome is that every time I add a new URL it will capture the `first_name`, `last_name` save them in a database and add new data to the list instead of starting from an empty list.

Here is the code:

```
url = 'website'

data_list=[]

def data():
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    name_array = soup.find_all('h1', {'class': 'Profile-userFullName-_EP'})
    name = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'Profile-userFullName-_EP'}).text.strip().split()
    first_name = name[0]
    last_name = name[1]

    data = [[first_name, last_name]]
    # data_list.append(data)
    return data

data_list.append(data())
print(len(data_list))
print (data_list)
```

***Edit***
As I am a newbie in this field, after searching for the best way to save generated data I decided to go with saving it into an excel sheet and add to it without overwriting the existing data using Pandas

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: "Error while appending to an empty List in Python" the fact that you are processing HTML is irrelevant to the question, so just make your function return `data` and go from there, you're more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: Also, you only do a single append so you might be missing a loop somewhere (when you speak of multiple values).

Comment: Whats the website you are using? So that I can recreate it in my device. And what is expected output

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, data() returns a single object, that is a list with 2 objects. So since you are appending only 1 object, list will always be one. If you provide expected output, I can add some code to fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be very vague. I guess you need to get a **list** of all the names in the list of `[firstname,lastname]` format. if it is so try the below code snippet.

```
url = 'website'

data_list=[]

def data():
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    name_array = soup.find_all('h1', {'class': 'Profile-userFullName-_EP'})
    for x in name_array:
      name = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'Profile-userFullName-_EP'}).text.strip().split()
      first_name = name[0]
      last_name = name[1]
      data = [first_name, last_name]
      data_list.append(data)

print(len(data_list))
print (data_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `data_list.append(data())`, `data_list` grows in size by 1. Since you call it once, your list is 1 in length. To illustrate,

```
data_list.append(data())
```

produces a `data_list` of length 1, while

```
data_list.append(data())
data_list.append(data())
data_list.append(data())
```

would produce a `data_list` of length 3.